# How should I install Mono Develop to work in MVC 5 projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mono, asp.net-mvc-5, monodevelop

Hey guys can somebody explain me the steps to properly install Mono Develop to create MVC 5 projects with all packages and dependencies that I would need to work on it. I used to work in Visual Studio on windows, but now I am stacked in Mono Develop on ubuntu.

Thank you guys, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a walk-through:

http://otac0n.com/blog/2015/02/08/running-mvc5-applications-on-ubuntu-server.html